# running rails app in production mode is not displaying the production server logs in terminal. and showing the error something went wrong in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, server, development-environment, production

When i run the rails app in development mode,server logs are displaying in terminal properly. But when i run the app in production mode server is not displaying any server logs in terminal. and an error is displaying in the browser like "We're sorry, but something went wrong.".i am running the server with the following command.and i am using the thin server.

```
rails s -e production
```

this is the output i am getting in server mode when i start the server.and after this when i made any request no output is displaying.

```
prashant@prashant-pc:~/client_proj/template$ rails s -e production
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

what might be issue i am not getting.

Comment: In `production.rb` what is the `config.log_level` set to?

Comment: config.log_level = :info

Comment: Once try it to set to `:debug` not sure it will help or not, just a try. And restrat the server after that and test.

Comment: i tried but of no use . still the same issue is coming.

Comment: Please check if there is necessary permission to create and write on the production.log file

Answer (score 3):

In `production.rb` you can add this option:
 `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

Answer (score 2):

If you see this block in the `production.rb`

```
  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
```

then you can simply set environment variable to any value with `export` before starting the `rails server`

```
$ export RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the environment variables `RAILS_ENV=production` and `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true` did the job for me (with Rails 7.0.4)